# check date database and execute

Tags: java, database, oracle

I have a table in database which contains start date and end date. Now what I need to do is that database should be checked once at night checking all end dates. if today is the day before the end date, then I can execute a java class that will send the email notification saying membership will expire. I am using oracle database and java (jsf) as development language.

My date stored in the  table is in my preferred format i.e. MM/DD/YYYY.

Thanks,

Comment: well I have no idea what mechanism to use to implement this. That's what am asking exactly. I found out something about DBMS_SCHEDULER but not sure how that would trigger the java class.

Comment: You need to create a separate application which will watch the database all the time. In My company such application is available with named Table Watcher.

Comment: no way of using a stored procedure or trigger?

Comment: if you can use a third party library use Quartz, a simple job class will do what you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Schedule a job](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/schedadmin006.htm) using `DBMS_SCHEDULER` to run a PL/SQL procedure at an interval you desire. The PL/SQL procedure can then [call your java method](http://qamarsyed.blogspot.com/2010/07/calling-java-from-plsql-inside-oracle.html) to send the email notification.

Comment: @sys_debug did you check the links? There are examples & code there.

Comment: Sorry didn't notice..Thanks, will check and get back to you :)